# create balls moving from the edge of the screen

Tags: android, canvas

I am doing a game .
It have balls will moving from the edge of the screen .To do it , I used a function random

```
public void random(){
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    x = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth());
    y = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());
    xSpeed = rnd.nextInt(10) - 5;
    ySpeed = rnd.nextInt(10) - 5;
    x = x + xSpeed;
    y = y + ySpeed;
}
```

If I used:

```
x = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()); 
y = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());
```

the balls will appear at any position. If I used:

```
x = 0, y = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());
```

the balls will appear along the axis Oy .

But I don't can for balls appear along all edge of the screen .
Please help me .Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

You can put some logic in your function like...

```
   x = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth());
y = rnd.nextInt(gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());
//here
if(x<y){
 x=0;
}

else if(y<x){
  y=0;
}
 else{
 x=0;
  y=0;
  }
```

this will always put your ball along the sides of your frame...